# rails: best way to store comments in mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay i have two models: posts and comments.
as you can think comments has column :post_id.

My models

**Comments**

- belongs_to :post

**Post**

- has_many :comments

So, this is pretty simple association but i have some problems with ordering comments.
at first time, when i create my comments migration file i just add column :position.
This column indicate comment position in the post.

But now i think what where is more good way to do this.

so i can't make my choise:

1) uses t.column :datatime :created_at, :default => Time.now()

2) or use timestamps? this is undiscovered for me, please tell me about your exp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yar is right. No need to have a `position` column, unless you'll want to reorder your comments, which I doubt you will :) Just do

```
has_many :comments, :order => "created_at DESC"
```

and every time you use `@post.comments` they will be sorted by date.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, all models automatically get a `created_at` field. You can just order by that.

Comment: i know. but i don't need updated_at column because users can't update weir comments :D